# scaffolding Laravel application based on the option

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, braintree, laravel-cashier

Since Laravel cashier does not support both Stripe and Braintree together. I want to give an option to the admin to choose between Stripe and Braintree at the time of the installation. The installer does not use composer install, I'll ship all vendor files with the code archive. In that case what will be the best way to handle this scenario?

BTW: I'm using Laravel 5.7 and cashier ^8.0 if this makes any sense.

Comment: Create a config file and add option there. so admin could switch from there... another thought :)

Comment: That will not work because both versions of cashier uses the same namespace.

Comment: I'm about to provide options to choose b/w Stripe & Braintree